# Android "hollow" color

Tags: android, colors, background

Is there any way of setting a "hollow" color in an Android application?

What I mean is that I'd like to have a box with some kind of background and the text would actually cause transparency of the background. In other words, if the entire view is on a blue background, the text will be blue, if it is on red, it will be red, if it is on an image, the image will be visible through the text but not through the rest of the box.

Comment: can you please draw something or post image to show how it would be, am just curious.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do it indeed. You'd have to use your own Paint object and draw text on the Canvas supplied in the onDraw() method. Then set this Xfermode on your Paint: new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR);

Comment: Right on, that seems to be a solution. Will have to play with it a little but it should be able to do the trick. Thanks @Romain